# PieCloudDB's data storage encryption

Tags: encryption, storage

PieCloudDB supports data storage encryption, but where is the default key of the storage encryption?

How can I access this encryption key?

Comment: (Couldn't find how to access PieCloudDB documentation in a language I know.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PieCloudDB supports TDE(Transparent Data Encryption),the encryption key is stored in the metadata. You can log in to metadata cluster using "fdbcli" command and execute the following command to get the key value:

```
listternants 

usetenant keytest； ###designate the corresponding tenant 

writenmode on ###open write mode 

###execute the following "get" command, querying the value of master key. 

get\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

[image]